# semantic-release fails to publish to npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, circleci, semantic-release

I am using semantic-release npm module to do the releases in circle ci. I am getting following error

> [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Write version 1.0.0 to
>   package.json in /home/circleci/tmp npm ERR! Version not changed, might
>   want --allow-same-version
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_21_36_194Z-debug.log [3:21:36
>   PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "prepare" of plugin
>   "@semantic-release/npm" [3:21:36 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error
>   occurred while running semantic-release: { Error: Command failed: npm
>   version 1.0.0 --no-git-tag-version npm ERR! Version not changed, might
>   want --allow-same-version
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_21_36_194Z-debug.log
>
> ```
> at makeError (/home/circleci/tmp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
> at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/circleci/tmp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   code: 1,   stdout: '',   stderr:    'npm ERR! Version not changed,
> ```
>
> might want --allow-same-version\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_21_36_194Z-debug.log\n',
>   failed: true,   signal: null,   cmd: 'npm version 1.0.0
>   --no-git-tag-version',   timedOut: false,   killed: false,   pluginName: '@semantic-release/npm' } { Error: Command failed: npm
>   version 1.0.0 --no-git-tag-version npm ERR! Version not changed, might
>   want --allow-same-version
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_21_36_194Z-debug.log
>
> ```
> at makeError (/home/circleci/tmp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
> at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/circleci/tmp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   code: 1,   stdout: '',   stderr:    'npm ERR! Version not changed,
> ```
>
> might want --allow-same-version\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T15_21_36_194Z-debug.log\n',
>   failed: true,   signal: null,   cmd: 'npm version 1.0.0
>   --no-git-tag-version',   timedOut: false,   killed: false,   pluginName: '@semantic-release/npm' }Exited with code 1

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error probably happen because you updated the version in `package.json` manually. You should let semantic-release doing that for you.

You should set the version in your `package.json` to `0.0.0-dev`. If you want to have the updated `package.json` pushed to your repo use the `@sematnic-release/git` plugin.

Comment: Yes, this exactly what has happened. Thanks :)